# MSSQL left join order by nulls to the end while if all nulls order by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have this mssql query

```
SELECT TOP 50 [id], [title], [url], [icon], linkstats.visits 
FROM [websites] LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkstats] ON websites.id=linkstats.lid AND linkstats.code=@country 
WHERE (([country] = @country OR [country]= 'all') AND 
      ([hot] = @hot)) 
ORDER BY linkstats.visits DESC
```

I want to order by nulls to the end and if all are nulls then order by ID
How to do that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CASE`

```
SELECT TOP 50 [id], [title], [url], [icon], linkstats.visits 
FROM [websites] LEFT OUTER JOIN [linkstats] ON websites.id=linkstats.lid AND linkstats.code=@country 
WHERE (([country] = @country OR [country]= 'all') AND 
      ([hot] = @hot)) 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN linkstats.lid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         linkstats.visits DESC
```

Comment: but when all values are null it orders the rows in the opposite way, which is the latest row in the table at first.. I want to make it ascending order when all values are null!, can u do that?!

Comment: And `..., [id] ASC`? (*‘if all are nulls then order by ID’* )